# Find all webparts by name in sandbox

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created a new webpart for SP2010 (in a new solution) that replaces an existing webpart. Now I need to find all sites where this webpart is used. What is the easiest way to do this?
My right are limited, but i am able to deploy solutions.

Thanks everyone in advanced,
Kai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for all Sandbox Solutions, your only hope is to enumerate all site collections via CSOM and check the Solutions property to get all the Sandbox Solutions published to that site.  That is the only way to see what Sandbox Solutions are in use in your farm. There isn't a centralized console of what Sandbox Solutions are in use.